# Query Azure table storage by list of partition and row key pairs

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have a list of known partition and row key pairs from the same table, (e.g P1R1, P2R2, P3R3, P-PartitionKey, R-Row key), anyone know how to query from Azure Table Storage to get these 3 entities in one request?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an option besides just spelling it out in the Where/Filter clause explicitly.

Comment: Hi, filter sounds a good option. I have same requirement, to query Azure Table with multiple partition key but I have one more constraint to pull N entities for each partition key. Is there a way to return N entities for each partition.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that, but you don't want to. It will result in a table scan and be extremely slow. You'd be much better served by firing off each request separately.

If you're dead set on doing it with one query, comment here and I'll get you the code. I'm on my iPad right now so I don't have it handy.